# How to add sources for Entries

Tags: plugin-development, sources

The documentation indicates it is possible to add sources for entries like this:

```
use craft\base\Element;
use craft\elements\Entry;
use craft\events\RegisterElementSourcesEvent;
use yii\base\Event;

Event::on(Entry::class, Element::EVENT_REGISTER_SOURCES, function(RegisterElementSourcesEvent $event) {
    if ($event->context === 'index') {
        $event->sources[] = [
            'heading' => \Craft::t('plugin-handle', 'Statuses'),
        ];

        foreach (Entry::statuses() as $status => $label) {
            $event->sources[] = [
                'key' => 'status:'.$status,
                'label' => $label,
                'criteria' => ['status' => $status]
            ];
        }
    }
});
```

Just implementing this example alone in a module will indeed add the sources in the left source column, but activating the source options do not present tables of element with the respective status, as expected.

How can I add sources that show entries with a specific status, as well as other criteria and what criteria options are possible to use?